# Erro ao executar relatório no Reporting Services do SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro ao executar algum relatório do Reporting Services:

> "Erro no processamento de relatório. (rsProcessingAborted) Não é
>   possível criar uma conexão com a fonte de dados 'Produção'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)"

Procedimentos realizados:

- Habilitado TCP/IP e Pipe Name nas configurações do SQL Server;
- Todos os serviços do SQL Server *startados*;
- Permitida conexão remota na instância do banco;
- Firewall e antivírus desabilitados no servidor.

Comment: Espero que isso ajude: [named-pipes-provider-error-40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Comment: ôpa @CaiodePaulaSilva, já tinha realizado todos esses passos.

Comment: O erro acontece com qualquer relatório ou com algum relatório específico? Esse relatório funcionava antes ou sempre deu esse erro? O erro acontece quando o relatório é disparado de alguma máquina específica ou de qualquer uma?

Answer (score 0):

## Opção 1

Resolver esse problema é fácil:

- Vá ate o executar (Win+R)
- Digite `services.msc`
- Reinicie o `MSSQLSERVER`

Traduzido de :
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9945409/)

## Opção 2

A primeira coisa que eu tentaria é obter um pouco mais de informação sobre o erro

- **Essa mensagem dada é bastante genérica.**

Você pode ativar `erros remotos` conforme a mensagem de erro e replicar o erro.
Para obter mais informações.

[Ativar erros remotos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/reporting-services/report-server/enable-remote-errors-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017)

Ou verificar os logs de erros do Report Server para ver qual erro foi registrado.

`%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<SQL Server Instance>\Reporting Services\LogFiles\`

A próxima etapa seria conectar como o usuário da fonte de dados ao banco de dados, executar qualquer código / procedimentos armazenados que o log esteja usando com os mesmos parâmetros que você está usando ao executar o relatório e ver se ocorrem erros.

Traduzido de :
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14589011/)

Outras leituras: [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a8f2e64-74cf-46f2-b2be-bbb08b1502cb/re-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlreportingservices)